# Which criteria are used by adblocker to detect ads

Tags: adblock

I'm using google adsense for my website which has around 3000 pages. All revenues for website comes through ads.
My question is that Which criteria adblockers use to detect Ads on web page ?
Do they detect banner size or `CSS` class or other keywords ?

Comment: I _feel_ SO isn't right place for this question however a _SO-style_ comment (not answer) may be: think you have to write a program to detect ads. What would you do? Searching for "ads" or "banner" is pretty fragile (even if yes, some ad blockers do it ALSO this way for specific _keywords_). Links are little bit more reliable (if you keep your "black list" updated). Multi-rule scoring is even more reliable (an iframe with id "advertising" may not be blocked but multiple "traces" may block a div (!!!) with id "site-navigation-banner"). I hope you get what I mean.

Comment: Anyway, what's better than inspect an ad blocker source code? There you 'll find many answers (at least for one specific case): https://github.com/adblockplus

Comment: blocking full url, partial url, 2nd layer rules such as 3rd-party, XMLHTTPRequest,  (and much more), for hiding: again- full/partial, minimal selector (# for id, . for class) or full CSS selectors including stuff such as `||domain.com#(class*="ads-")^`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adblock programs generally subscribe to lists of rules, which provide guidelines for detecting whether a piece of content is an ad or not: For example, it might say "something with a class of 'ad' is almost definitely an ad!" Or it might say "any content delivered from a google adsense server has got to be an ad!"

[EasyList](https://easylist.adblockplus.org/en/) is one of those lists. You can read through it and see all its rules.

So to answer your question - yes! They look at banner size. Yes! they look at css. But they also check to see where the content is being delivered from, so if it's coming from google adsense, they can just classify the content as advertising on that basis.