# Getting 'blocked:other' error status from the browser - In Angular application, I made a rest API call to fetch the information from the server

Tags: angular, rest, http

Sample requested rest API URL: http://basepath/controller/api?bannerId=1&value=23

Getting browser error status: `blocked:other`, when we made an HTTP call to the server from the Angular application.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

When we have query params like 'adBanner', 'ad' & 'bannerId' etc.. in the API url, it will be blocked by 'AdBlock' extension from the browser. 
In my case, there is a 'bannerId' keyword in the query params. So it is blocked by the browser extension.

For other keywords which are used by AdBlocker, please refer to the below url
https://easylist.to/easylist/easylist.txt.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/33174424/5722465

Comment: Exaclty, adBlocker blocks url if contains ad like words 

Comment: It takes me a sunrise to debug

Comment: Thanks! For me it was disabling the Honey extension

Answer (score 0):

keyword `bannerId` is blocked by adblock, simple solution just to add mock params in the first place so like this `http://basepath/controller/api?preventAdblock=true&bannerId=1&value=23`