# JPG Image not showing in React Js

Tags: css, reactjs

I am simply trying to add a background image for a div. But some images show up and some don't.

I tried multiple ways like directly giving the image path in background-image property in css, importing the image in my jsx file and then setting it to the background image. The weird thing is that some images show up but some don't. At first I thought maybe its a problem with the file size or extension but I tried with two images with same resolution, same jpg extension and almost the same file size but one worked and the other didn't. Does anyone know why this happens and how can I fix it.

CSS

```
.features-container {
  background-image: linear-gradient(
      to right bottom,
      rgba(57, 62, 70, 0.6),
      rgba(34, 40, 49, 0.6)
    ),
    url("../assets/ads2.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
```

I have two jpg Images in my assets folder

[image: Two JPG Images in the assets folder]

Resolution of both images are 1920 x 1080, First image is 598kb while the second one is 531kb.

But when I change the url from the above css code to `url("../assets/ads1.jpg")`, it stops working.

Comment: maybe   background: url than url?, did u try it with other images like copy the working one to the filename of the not working? sounds like more the image is broken

Comment: I just tried it and the problem is not with the image but the name. If I change the name of the first image to ads2.jpg it starts working. I really don't understand what is happening here. :((

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was actually occurring due to the adblocker. I checked the request url the browser was using to get the images in the network tab of chrome dev tools and the status code of one of the images was (blocked:other). To solve the problem I simply disabled my adblocker and the problem resolved.

This happened because I had the word "ad" in my image filename and the adblocker was blocking it. If you want to further explore, why this occurs, the following post helped me a lot

https://stackoverflow.com/a/56048381